# How to execute a SQL statement with a variable as WHERE?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have some Java code like

```
int userid = take user input;
```

And then execute following sql statement,

```
        Class.forName(dbdriver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        st = conn.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("select * from person where uid = userid" );
```

Now, I don't know the returned result is `null`. I think  `where uid = userid` is giving wrong result because it is searching for literal uid value "userid". Actually, I want to retrive information from person table about user provided uid values. Can anybody help me how to solve this?

Comment: Can you show the actual java code where you do the query? Exactly how you pass the value of `userid` into the query depends a lot on how you are making the JDBC call.

Comment: Show us your code and stacktrace.?

Comment: Can you include the actual code you are running, and describe in more detail what behavior you observe?

Comment: This is pretty basic. Have you ever started *really* learning the subject using the official tutorials? Start here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html Particularly the chapter "Prepared Statements" should be helpful.

Comment: Srry, I make mistake st.executeUpdate("select * from person where uid =" + userid).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ResultSet rs = stmd.executeQuery("select * from person where uid = "+ userid);

while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("Name= " + rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: This has the risk of SQL injection. User Jasonw answer instead.

Answer (score 9):

You should use prepare statement as it protect you from sql injection. You can also add a simple logging by printing out the sql statement before it is executed and so you are sure. Below is the example class but feel free to change it in your situation.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class DBAccess
{
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    Connection con;

    DBAccess() throws Exception
    {
        String dbdriver = "";
        String url = "";
        String username = "";
        String password = "";

        Class.forName(dbdriver);

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }

    public Person getPerson(int userid) throws Exception
    {
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from person where uid = ?");
        pstmt.setInt(1, userid);
        System.out.println("sql query " + pstmt.toString());
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next())
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            return person;

        }
        return null;        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Could you paste the whole code block about this question?
Following is my suggestion

```
int userid = get user id ;
Connection connection = get connection ;
String sql = "select * from person where uid=?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setInt(1,userid);
```

if the database has one or more record which is uid filed equal the userid ,that will return the correct result

Answer (score -1):

int user_id=2003; // you can also get input variable

String sql="SELECT * FROM employment WHERE id=";

resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql+user_id);